# Most efficient way to make ajax request for a particular element

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been playing with jQuery .load function to grab a particular div from a page.

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #variable123');
```

This works like it should, however it is taking forever because the Response still contains the complete document even though all that is returned in #result is the div that I defined.. in this example #variable123

Is there another way I could accomplish this but only have the response contain that actual div?  What would be the fastest way to return this result?

To further clarify, the id that I am searching for is generated from a foreach loop on each page.

```
<img name="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>"
```

and then an onclick event for them to make the ajax request for that related div id.

```
   $('img').click(function () {  
      $('#result').load('ajax/test.html .' + $(this).attr("name"));
   });
```

The page test.html also has a foreach loop that generates div blocks with the same id as was passed in the name.  David and Juan both suggested sever side solutions.  Can someone please explain this a bit more to me?

Comment: this is not the client side, this si the server side to send dthe data only you need.

Comment: Are you using a server language?

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't fetch arbitrary **parts** of a file:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test_with_only_variable123_in_it.html');
```

You can, of course, use a server side program instead of generating a bundle of static files.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more to help me understand this?

Comment: You put just what you need in the file you request instead of putting in lots of things.

Answer (score 1):

As others suggested, you need to implement the functionality server side, not client side. It is not possible to use javascript to load part of a html file, so you'll either need to have an individual html file for every result you'll require (as David suggested), or create a server side script to manage this for you. For example:

Your html/js file would look like this:

```
 $('img').click(function () {  
   $('#result').load('ajax/test.php?id=' + $(this).attr('name'));
 });
```

I would probably use .get() or .ajax() over .load() to pass the data, but for this example, .load() should work as above.

In your test.php file, get the ID, and load the required content (something like this):

```
<?php 
// load class/model/whatever you need to do

$id = $_GET['id'];
$product = $productmodel->get($id); // or however you load a single product from your class/model

// echo data from $product
?>
```

If the second part doesn't make sense, please let us know how your products are stored ( whether you're using a simple OO approach, or using a php framework such as codeigniter) and we'll try to give a more detailed example of the server side code.

Comment: Thanks for the further explanation Christian.  It is starting to make sense and I understand what I need to do.. just struggling with how to write it.  Yet is is just OO, working on the Magento platform.  I call the products with this <?php $_product = $this->getProduct() ?>

Comment: Wouldnt I need to create some kind of if/else logic? If it matches the variable passed through that parameter, then it echos just the info for that product id?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't worked with Magento so I'm not quite sure how it's structured. However, you should be able to call $this->getProduct($id) (ie, passing the $id parameter to the getProduct() method) and it should just return the product that matches the requested ID, thus avoiding the need for any if/else logic.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to call to a function like this:

```
$('#target').load("functions.php",{action:"that_div"});

if($_POST){  
    $action = $_POST['action'];  
    if($action == "that_div"){  
        exit( "<div>Your div</div>" );  
    }    
    if($action == "another_div"){  
        exit("<div>Your another div</div>");  
    }  
}
```

as David sugested